# knife boostrap interactive installation

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe, knife

I'm currently new on chef/knife bootstrap installation and I was trying to install sophos on the node. During the installation it will ask something like `Where do you want to install Sophos Anti-Virus?` and my input will be `[/opt/sophos]`. How to do this on a chef recipe?

I'm trying to search on internet but couldn't find really an answer or any sample scripts that will help me.

Any help on this, will be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: I would recommend on reading the Sophos installation documentation and look for "How to do Sohos silent installation" and "What are the command line options available". 
If you're able to find this, then it becomes easy to automate via Chef.

Comment: @SaravananG Hi, I've tried installing it silently by using this command `bash /tmp/sophos-install/sophos-av/install.sh --SavWebUsername=username --SavWebPassword=password --update-source-type=n --acceptlicence --automatic ` but it returns `You must specify an installation directory on the command line for automatic installations.`

So yeah, I'm still trying to find out what is the command line for that one.